# Binet's Formula for Negative Fibonacci Sequences

Tags: matrices, exponentiation, matrix-calculus, fibonacci-numbers

I have recently learnt the Binet's formula for calculating Fibonacci Sequences and got my mind blown.

$F_n = \frac{(1+\sqrt{5})^n-(1-\sqrt{5})^n}{2^n \sqrt{5}}$

This has worked charm for positive numbers, however I am wondering if this could be applied to the negative Sequences as well. Here is an example:

Correct me if I am wrong, but this should be the Fib Series in General right:?

```
Fib(n) =  -6 -5 -4 -3 -2 -1 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 ...
FibValue= -8 -5 -3 -2 -1 -1 0 1 1 2 3 5 8 ...
```

Comment: Not quite. You should be careful in the arithmetic; either using a backwards recurrence or the Binet formula, you should get terms of alternating sign. For instance, see here (the terms for $n = -10, n = -9, ..., n = 10$) - [link](https://is.gd/1UiTLF). But generally, yes,

$$F_{-n} = (-1)^{n+1} F_n$$

when we identify our recurrence as having $F_0 = F_1 = 1$ and the usual recursion. You may also be interested in [this Wikipedia page](https://is.gd/ejAAuM) on the generalization.

Comment: Yes, the formula is mind-blowing. As a follow up, you should watch [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ghxQA3vvhsk) at Stand-up Maths YouTube channel.